# Is this an example of selectors?

Tags: jquery

I see the following piece of code

```
input[type='button']text:visible:enabled:first
```

What does this code do. Which feature of jquery is this? Is this selector example? Any links to read more on it?

Comment: [Yes/no questions about an example are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions). Answers to such questions are rarely useful to anyone except the original asker. The purpose of this site is to create a useful repository of high quality questions with answers. Instead of asking "is this an example of _X_", ask "what is _X_". What makes you think it is **not** an example of a selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That exact piece of code is not a valid selector, but if you split them up they are filters and they are used to make a selector.

```
$('input[type="button"]') // references <input type=button>
```

The others are just filters denoted by the colon.

```
:text //matches all input type=text
:visible //*tries* to return what elements are visible
:enabled //matches elements that are enabled
:first //grabs the first in the selector set.

Usage: $('el:visible')
```

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: is this example also of selector     --   $(this).focus().select();

Comment: No. Selectors *select* something, that just invokes a method called 'select'.

Comment: By *select* I mean they return an array of html element(s).

Comment: thank you very much for your asnwers. Is this some sort of a  chaining mechanism to be able do focus().select()? any link to read more on it

Answer (score 0):

That's probably intended to be a selector, yes.  I don't think the **input[type='button']text** portion is going to work though.

The jQuery documentation has a good rundown of all the various selectors:  http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Also check out [SelectorGadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/).  It's an interactive selector building GUI that loads right into your browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a selector, assuming that it is in something like this $() or this $j().  If I am reading it right it is looking for:

**input** any input
**[type='button']**
 with the type button
that is 
**:visible**
**:enabled** 
**:first** and the first such element.

(Unfortunately, as it stands it is also broken.)

See
http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type='button']
```

Is a selector, though in jQuery it needs to be wrapped in $(" ") to do something.

This kind of selector is bigger than a jQuery feature, it's XPath  http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/default.asp , which is a system of selecting pieces ("nodes") of XML. The HTML we use in web pages is a sort of XML and XPath is a type of statement you can apply to HTML if you want to find ('select') certain pieces of it.

So jQuery allows you to use XPath query statements as selectors. XPath queries are just one type of selector that jQuery provides access to, there are also CSS selectors http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_syntax.asp, which is a different system. As others have mentioned, read up on the jQuery selector documentation http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors, which should help explain a lot.